# How to avoid clipping text in WPF textbox with fixed height and width?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, asp.net-core

I am trying to AutoScale Font size if the text size is greater than the width or height of the box.
I am doing this

`// textbox padding & margins excluded
if (formattedText.WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace  > textbox.ActualWidth)
            {
                do
                {
                    // reduce font size by step
                    fontSize -= 1.0;
                    // set fontsize ready for re-measure
                    formattedText.SetFontSize(fontSize);
                } while ((formattedText.WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace > 
                        textbox.ActualWidth) && (fontSize > minimumFontSize));
            }
    myTextBox.FontSize = fontSize;
    return fontSize;`

But text is getting clipped or cropped.
Please see attached snapshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRVcF.png)
The Red marker is the border of textbox.
Can anyone suggest what should I do?
I have also tried 
`if (formattedText.Width> textbox.ActualWidth)
if (formattedText.Extent> textbox.ActualWidth)`

Thanks

Comment: Try putting the TextBox (or TextBlock?) in a Viewbox.

Comment: thanks for the response is that possible to put it into viewbox programmatically?

Comment: Sure, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.viewbox.child?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: This is to update stackoverflow community that the solution provided by @Keithernet below works fine with most of the cases but problem replicates when text is Bold. Please have a look at ScreenShot [here](https://ibb.co/ZKcvHRG) Screenshot font size is 9 although minimum font size limit is 06.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work with a multi-line TextBox, you need to do a couple extra things.

- You need to set a `MaxTextWidth` on the FormattedText so that it will calculate the Height properly
- If your `TextBox` style has `Padding` make sure to account for that in your `Width` and `Height` calculations

Here is a working example:

```
private void AdjustText()
{
    var dpiInfo = VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(MyTextBox);

    var fontSize = MyTextBox.FontSize;
    var minimumFontSize = 8;

    var typeface = new Typeface(MyTextBox.FontFamily,
        MyTextBox.FontStyle,
        MyTextBox.FontWeight,
        MyTextBox.FontStretch);

    var formattedText = new FormattedText(
        MyTextBox.Text,
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture,
        MyTextBox.FlowDirection,
        typeface,
        fontSize,
        MyTextBox.Foreground,
        dpiInfo.PixelsPerDip);

    formattedText.MaxTextWidth = MyTextBox.Width - (MyTextBox.Padding.Left + MyTextBox.Padding.Right);

    if (formattedText.Height > MyTextBox.Height - (MyTextBox.Padding.Top + MyTextBox.Padding.Bottom))
    {
        do
        {
            // reduce font size by step
            fontSize -= 2.0;
            // set fontsize ready for re-measure
            formattedText.SetFontSize(fontSize);
        } while (formattedText.Height > MyTextBox.Height - (MyTextBox.Padding.Top + MyTextBox.Padding.Bottom) && fontSize > minimumFontSize);

        MyTextBox.FontSize = fontSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unforunately, I don't work with .NET Core 2.2, so I don't know.

Comment: I am able to run this successfully and it worked too.
But when I changed the reductionStep `fontSize -= 2.0;` to `fontSize -= 0.2;` same problem replicates.
So with dynamic length and size of Text it may also reproduce with `fontSize -= 2.0;`
Is that possible?
Thanks

Comment: WPF has always had issues with the internal math around font sizes and scaling. I'm not sure how FormattedText works internally, so it's hard to say.

Comment: Hi Keithernet, just wanted to ask can you suggest any good way to dynamically reduce font size instead of hard coded value i-e 0.2 or 2.0 ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any advice to offer. Sorry about that.

Comment: This is to update stackoverflow community that above solution works fine with most of the cases but problem replicated when text contains four lines.
Please have a look at ScreenShot [here](https://ibb.co/ZKcvHRG)
Screenshot font size is 9 although minimum font size limit is 06.

Comment: Solution above also works if the text is not Bold.
When I make it "Bold" it cuts

Comment: thanks for your support, its pretty much late to respond here but for somebody else making the same mistake may find it helpful.
I was able to fix this passing "Verdana" is fallback font family in formattedText object which results in fixing this crop of text issue :) So it was the font which was making trouble calculating the exact height and width of formattedText